# Cors: unencrypted origin trusted in NextJS 12

Tags: security, next.js, cors

I am new to NextJS and I have a web application developed using NextJS 12, which I am hosting in Google Cloud.

My team has a run a Security Scan and they found these issues :

- **Cross-origin resource sharing: unencrypted origin trusted**\

For example :

**Severity** : Low
**Path** : /_next/data/f_xdDDLA/dashboard.json \

**Issue detail**
The application implements an HTML5 cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) policy for this request which trusts websites accessed using unencrypted communications

**Request:**

GET /_next/data/f_xdDDLA/dashboard.json
....other request information...
Origin: **http**://mywebsite.com

**Response**

HTTP/2 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Nextjs-Matched-Path: /dashboard
X-Powered-By: Next.js
**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**: **http**://mywebsite.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Same thing for any URL in my application like : mywebsite.com/edit-request they can send a request with non https origin and it can be accepted

I read that NextJS has by default same-origin policy but it doesn't seem to work in this case. and I don't have any CORS configuration in my project

I tried this in the file config.next.js :

```
const nextConfig = {
  // Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/react-strict-mode
  reactStrictMode: true,
  // i18n,
  async headers () {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Strict-Transport-Security',
            value: 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
          },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', value: 'true' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: 'https://mywebsite.com' } 
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I still have the same issues.

I also have other security issues like :

- **Cross-origin resource sharing: all subdomains trusted**
  **Issue background**
  An HTML5 cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) policy controls whether and how content running on other domains can perform two-way interaction with the domain that publishes the policy. The policy is fine-grained and can apply access controls per-request based on the URL and other features of the request.

If an application allows interaction from all subdomains, then this significantly increases its attack surface. For example, a cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability in any subdomain could potentially compromise the application that publishes the policy. Some consumer ISPs return custom content when requests are made to unregistered subdomains, which can introduce XSS vulnerabilities even if all of an organization's own applications are secure.

**Issue remediation**
Rather than trusting all subdomains, use a whitelisted of trusted subdomains.

If you can help with fixing these issues please

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Are you sure you're actually only listing `https://mywebsite.com` as an allowed origin in CORS configuration? `http://mywebsite.com` (no `s`) shouldn't be allowed, because it indeed makes your users vulnerable to cross-origin attacks in case of a MitM. To understand why, read the section entitled _Breaking HTTPS_ in https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties. However, if HSTS is properly configured for `mywebsite.com`, then that finding effectively is a false positive.

Comment: @jub0bs I don't have a Cors configuration in my project, and I don't know how to specify only https in NextJS

Comment: According to the `config.next.js` you've shared in your question, you're trying to set configure HSTS and CORS in there...

Comment: @jub0bs I had the security issue before updating details in config.next.js, when I updated the file nothing changed

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @jub0bs I mean I don't want to configure CORS, the file `config.next.js` was just a tentative t resolve the security issues otherwise I will keep the default NextJS `config.next.js` file.
So imagine if I don't have a CORS configuration, how can I limit the origin of requests to be HTTPS only ?

Comment: You ask: _how can I limit the origin of requests to be HTTPS only_. Not with CORS, anyway, since [_simple_ requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) are allowed by the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: @jub0bs that's what I find online and that's what make me confused. No one is talking about limiting the origin to HTTPS since it's done by the browser automatically but when they use their security tool it shows them that as a vulnerability.

I tried to do that using Postman, when I inspect and get copy the request from Network tab as CuRL I can play with the request in Postman and update the origin to a non https one